# scala type erasure - matching case class

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, type-erasure

I was reading about type erasure, [here](https://squidarth.com/scala/types/2019/01/11/type-erasure-scala.html)

```
case class Thing[T](value: T)

def processThing(thing: Thing[_]) = {
  thing match {
    case Thing(value: Int) => "Thing of int"         //isn't thing Thing[_] anymore?
    case Thing(value: String) => "Thing of string"   //isn't thing Thing[_] anymore?
    case Thing(value: Seq[Int]) => "Thing of Seq[Int]"         //value=Seq[_] really
    case Thing(value: Seq[String]) => "Thing of Seq[String]"   //value=Seq[_] really
    case _ => "Thing of something else"
  }
}
println(processThing(Thing(Seq(1,2,3))))          //type erased, I get it
println(processThing(Thing(Seq("hello", "yo"))))  //type erased, I get it
println(processThing(Thing(1)))                   //why is this working?
println(processThing(Thing("hello")))             //why is this working?
```

I understand why Seq[Int] and Seq[String] are not identified correctly, at runtime both are seen like Seq[Object].

However, I do not understand why the first two examples ARE working:
why Thing[Int] and Thing[String], both being Thing[T]
are NOT having the same problem that Seq[T] has...

Why Thing[Seq[T]] is type erased
but Thing[T] (T=Int, String) is not?

Can anybody explain what is going on here? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right that at runtime both `Thing(1)` and `Thing("Hello")` will erase to the same class `Thing`.

Thus, if you do something like this:

```scala
thing match {
  case _: Thing[Int] => foo
  case _: Thing[String] => bar
}
```

You would see the behavior you expected.

However, your pattern match is doing something different, it extracts the value inside `thing` and then performs a class check on that.
The class information of the value is preserved by itself so that is why you can distinguish between `Int`, `String` and `Seq`, but you can't see what was the type parameter of the `Seq`
But, you may try to check the first element of the `Seq` ... but that still won't be enough, since the first element may be a `Dog` and the second a `Cat` because it was a `Seq[Animal]` and that check is even more unsafe than the previous ones since the `Seq` may be empty.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following Java code:

```java
class Foo {
  <T> void bar(T whatIsIt) {
    System.out.println("It is a: " + whatIsIt.getClass().getName());
  }

  public static void main() {
    Foo f = new Foo();
    f.bar(123);
    f.bar("Hello world");
    f.bar(f);
    f.bar(new ArrayList<String>());
  }
}
```

At runtime there exists only one method `Foo#bar(Object)`.  But the object that is passed in as `whatIsIt` still has a pointer to whatever class it *actually* is.

Scala has access to the same metadata that Java does.  So when it builds the bytecode for `processThing` it can insert `value instanceOf Integer` - and that's what it does:

```
scala> :javap processThing

// ... snip ...

  public java.lang.String processThing($line3.$read$$iw$Thing<?>);
    descriptor: (L$line3/$read$$iw$Thing;)Ljava/lang/String;
    flags: (0x0001) ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=8, args_size=2
         0: aload_1
         1: astore_3
         2: aload_3
         3: ifnull        29
         6: aload_3
         7: invokevirtual #37                 // Method $line3/$read$$iw$Thing.value:()Ljava/lang/Object;
        10: astore        4
        12: aload         4
        14: instanceof    #39                 // class java/lang/Integer
        17: ifeq          26
        20: ldc           #41                 // String Thing of int

// ... snip ...
```

Comment: sorry, I am still lost. The arg for process is a Thing[Int] or Thing[String] object. I do expect that Thing type will be known inside the method (as a generic Thing[_]), but not its actual type param (Int or String).

Comment: The point is that given `Object value = new Integer(3);` (which is what `Thing[T](value: T); Thing(3)` shakes out to) it is possible to introspect (via `instanceof` and `(Cast)` what the runtime class of a given value is.  But if you have a container, you can't find out what the runtime _generic_ class is (only infer it from the runtime type of the things contained in that instance).  E. g. `Thing(Thing(3))`.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense. When looking at the "thing" object I can only see Thing[ _ ] but if I extract the value inside it (via pattern matching), I will get the type of "value" which is a plain Int or String (no type erasure here). So basically by doing the pattern matching I can get access the members of my Thing class (and their types), whereas by looking at Seq, all I get is Seq[_] and no extra type information

Comment: @chris just remember you are not looking at their types, just their classes. Those are different: https://typelevel.org/blog/2017/02/13/more-types-than-classes.html